# Why I am getting error while using n98-magrun2 command "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Magento\ApplicationPerformanceMonitor\Plugin\Applicatio"

Tags: magento2, indexer

I am getting the below error while running the command `n98-magerun2 list`:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Magento\ApplicationPerformanceMonitor\Plugin\ApplicationPerformanceMonitor::aroundLaunch(): Return value must be of type Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface, null returned in app/code/Magento/ApplicationPerformanceMonitor/Plugin/ApplicationPerformanceMonitor.php:38
```

I am unable to find any resolution on Google. Please help me. Thanks in advance.